# Need help finding out why my code doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a project for school, and with the code I have made so far, I don't see why I can't do what I want to do.

The basic idea of it is I am making an app to keep track of howmany 'resources' someone has in a boardgame. The app has 4 buttons per resource, +1, +5, -1, and -5. When A person clicks a button, the text next to the resource picture should update with the amount of resources the player has left. (I didn't get to this yet, wouldn't know how to do it either).

My issue comes with the adding/removing of the amount of resources when someone presses a button. Rather than having all the buttons count on the same value, they all work on the same variable, but with a different variable
(I.E. When I press the +1 3x, it shows 3, but when I click the +5 it shows 5, then when I press +1 again it shows 4. Press the +5 again and it shows

I can't even think of any other way to do it... I have tried different ways of adding it up, but they all lead to the same problem.

```
public int totalWood = 0;

public void addOneWood()
{
    totalWood += 1;
    Debug.Log("Amount added!");
    print(totalWood);
}
public void addFiveWood()
{
    totalWood += 5;
    Debug.Log("Amount added!");
    print(totalWood);
}
public void delOneWood()
{
    totalWood -= 1;
    Debug.Log("Amount Removed!");
    print(totalWood);
}
public void delFiveWood()
{
    totalWood -= 5;
    Debug.Log("Amount Removed!");
    print(totalWood);
}
```

Expected results:
Pressing +1 x3 shows 3, Pressing +5 x1 should show 8.
Pressing +1 x1 again should show 9.

Reality:
Pressing +1 x3 shows 3, pressing +5 shows 5.
Pressing +1 x1 again shows 4.

Comment: how do you use this class in the wider context of your app

Comment: How are you calling these functions? Through clicking on buttons or through key press?

Comment: You are probably attaching the script to each button, you probably need to store the resources at a player level and update their wood resource as the button is pressed, I hope that helps

Comment: @Flexicoder I had at first given all the seperate buttons a different scripts, undoing this all by addingthe script to the canvas and removing it from the seperate buttons makes it so that I cant start the clickevent as it doesnt recognize the script for the buttons. (I hope I put that a bit clear?)

Comment: @ReinierJongerius I dont think you are doing it right. Here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tQsLD9GWrw

Comment: Now that your question has been answered, I'd like to add, that if this is C#, the standard is for methods and properties to be capitalized :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me. I am assuming you have attached this script to each button in the scene. So do not make this mistake. Just add this script to one GameObject and make all buttons be reference to this gameObject. Hope you got it. I have updated your script with keypress (A,S,Y,X) to test the "totalWood" value. Test it yourself.

UPDATE: Text property

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; //Very important

public class Wood : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int totalWood = 0;
    public Text totalWoodText; //attach your text component here
    void Update()
    {
        totalWoodText.text = totalWood.ToString(); //just one line command

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            addOneWood();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            addFiveWood();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Y))
        {
            delOneWood();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            delFiveWood();
        }


    }
    public void addOneWood()
    {
        totalWood += 1;
        Debug.Log("Amount added!");
        print(totalWood);
    }
    public void addFiveWood()
    {
        totalWood += 5;
        Debug.Log("Amount added!");
        print(totalWood);
    }
    public void delOneWood()
    {
        totalWood -= 1;
        Debug.Log("Amount Removed!");
        print(totalWood);
    }
    public void delFiveWood()
    {
        totalWood -= 5;
        Debug.Log("Amount Removed!");
        print(totalWood);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
public static int totalWood = 0;
```

Explanation:

This because the fired event from button pressure will instance a new object of the defined class hence you will init the totalWood by ZERO each time you click!

NOTE: the value will be kept the time the app is launching, and if under any reason the app closed it will reinit again to ZERO, if you need a permanent storage you have to use a one of data management approaches such as JSON, DBMS and the like

Comment: Hey I had another question... Now that it all works, id like to have the integer transfered into a string that I can use for a text visible on screen. I've looked online a bit but I dont understand any methods other people give... Could you give an explanation/example?

Here's my code as I have it now:

            public void totalWoodCount()
            {
            totalWood.ToString(woodAmount);
            }

Comment: @Saif Thanks a lot! I had some trouble setting it up at first, but managed to find it out at the end :)

Really appreciate the help you guys! (I may come at you with future questions too :P)